# как обратиться к значениям в массиве

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
// есть массив нужно отнять от первого второе и от второго третье и тд и записать в новый массив
var s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] //в массив по хорошему  приходит разное количество значений
for i in s {
    s[i] = s[i-2] - s[i-1]
}
```

Comment: а можно сразу пример результата. не совсем понятно - отнять от первого второе и записать в первое? потом от второго третье и записать во второе?

Comment: и что делать с последним, поскольку следующего нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var s2 = [Int]()
for index in 0..<s1.count-1 {
    s2.append(s1[index]-s1[index+1])
}
```